# C, GTK+, сигналы

Tags: c, windows, signal, gtk+

1) Подскажите, в чем разница между функциями, и есть ли эта разница вообще:

```
g_signal_connect();
gtk_signal_connect();
```

2) В чем смысл функции:

```
g_signal_connect_swapped();
```

Answer (score 0):

В книге:

*GTK+ Gnome Application Development*

Havoc Pennington

Red Hat Advanced Development Labs

есть описание функции *gtk_signal_connect()*:

**gtk_signal_connect()** specifies the GtkObject to monitor, which signal to connect to, the callback to connect, and finally a user_data argument—this is an arbitrary gpointer which will be passed to the callback. The macro GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC() casts the callback to a standard function signature; since callbacks have a variety of type signatures, the alternative would be dozens of gtk_signal_connect() variants.

А где Вы наткнулись на *g_signal_connect()*? Может быть это одно и тоже в разных версиях библиотеки GTK+ ?

Comment: Судя по всему, делает оно одно и тоже. Я попытался покопаться в исходниках, чтобы найти, может, действительно, g_ - это просто следствие переноса функции из GTK в GLib, но найти typedef/define мне не удалось. Нашел я это случайно, когда разбирался с примером. Только потом заметил, что я написал g_ вместо gtk_. Как оказалось, оно работает и так, и так.

Comment: Я что-то слышал о переносе присоединителя сигналов из GTK+ в GLib, но не помню, откуда эта информация, к сожалению.